# MATCH inside FOREACH -ish construct in cypher with Neo4j 2.0.1

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher

I have a Neo4j 2.0.1. datastore with 10k docs and 12k terms inter-related through 12M rels like

```
(:doc)-[:HAS_TERM]->(:term)
```

Sometimes I need to find similar docs, based on a count of common terms. For a specific doc, the 3 most similar docs are retrieved using cypher:

```
MATCH (d1:doc)-[:HAS_TERM]->(t)<-[:HAS_TERM]-(d2:doc) 
WHERE d1.id = 'ABC123' AND d2 <> d1
WITH d1,d2,count(t) as commonterms 
MATCH (d1)-[t1:HAS_TERM]->()
RETURN d2.id,(commonterms*100/count(t1)) AS commontermsperc
ORDER BY commontermsperc desc 
LIMIT 3
```

works fine, but it's expensive. Since the terms linked to the docs do not change frequently, I want to create additional relationships between docs that are similar, like

```
(:doc)-[:IS_SIMILAR_TO]->(:doc)
```

preferably in a periodically executed cypher. Something of this structure  (not working cypher because it does not allow MATCH inside a FOREACH

```
MATCH (d:doc)
WITH COLLECT(d) AS ds
FOREACH (d1 in ds |
    MATCH (d1)-[:HAS_TERM]->(t)<-[:HAS_TERM]-(d2) 
    WHERE d1.id = 'ABC123' AND d2 <> d1
    WITH d1,d2,count(t) as commonterms 
    MATCH (d1)-[t1:HAS_TERM]->()
    WITH d1,d2,(commonterms*100/count(t1)) AS commontermsperc ORDER BY commontermsperc desc LIMIT 3
    CREATE (d1)-[:IS_SIMILAR_TO {score:commontermsperc]->(d2)
)
```

The question is  : can this be done in cypher?

Comment: Could the downvoter perhaps explain why  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to use Cypher to do an iterative algorithm over your entire graph. This is what is called a "graph global query". As of Neo4j 2.0.1, graph global queries are not easy to do in Cypher. What would be better is if you ran a messaging queue that iterated through each of your docs to do the ranking.

This can be accomplished performantly using the Neo4j Transactional Endpoint. You can post multiple Cypher statements to a transaction context.

See the reference documentation for more details on this:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html

Comment: thanks for pointing out. wasn't are of it. transactions seem the way to tackle this.